# Ionic 4 ion-refresher reloading the whole page

Tags: ionic4

When I load infinite scroll many items and scroll to top to load ion refresher 
it loads the full page again

```
        <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)" pullFactor="1.2">
        <ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="lines" refreshingSpinner="crescent"></ion-refresher-content>
      </ion-refresher>

      <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="maindiv">

   {{item.name}}
    </div>

    <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" id="infinite_scroller" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="dots"></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

[error example](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/images/2017/11/overscroll-behavior/mobilep2r.mp4)

and the ts code to get items

```
  doRefresh(event) {
    this.page=0;


    setTimeout(() => {
        this.service.list(this.page)
         .subscribe(res => {
           this.items = res;
          event.target.complete();
        });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Comment: please explain more clearly what the issue is and also share your ts code

Comment: What is the code in doRefresh()?

Comment: the ts code is added